# How to link to an individual web content item in Liferay?

Tags: liferay

Let's say that I am using an AUI Carousel to display a news item slideshow.

This is a typical slideshow - a series of images with overlay text and each image/overlay text links to a web content article for the site's news.

It seems that with Liferay 6.2, it's only possible to link to a page containing the article rather than the article itself.

How does one link to an individual article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to use a Display Page; starting with Liferay 6.1, there is the concept of Canonical URLs (see [here](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/features-of-liferays-wcm-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-02-en)).

In order to use this, you need two things:

- an asset publisher page (in my example here, the page is called **News**)
- when creating the web content item, set the **Display Page** to the above (**News**)

Now the content item can be referred to via: `http(s)://<site-url>/-/<web-content-item-url-title>`

So, if I have a web content item with the name **Come Join Us For Lunch**, and a site url of `http://my-site.com/`, the canonical URL for this web content item will be `http://my-site.com/-/come-join-us-for-lunch`

However, you should always get the actual url-title from

```
JournalArticle.getUrlTitle()
```